# Spring JdbcTemplate is update atomic?

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Is the following jdbcTemplate update script is threadsafe? what it does basically is :

```
balance -= amount;
```

Here is the code:

```
String sql = "update player.playerbalance b set b.balance = (b.balance - ?) where b.id = ? and b.balance >= ?";

jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

int i = jdbcTemplate.update(
            sql,
            new Object[] {wager, playerBalance.getId(), wager});
```

What happens if two updates of this kind happens at the same time?

Thanks,

Comment: you will get an exception: `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` or `OptimisticLockingFailureException` or another..

Comment: But i didn't define locking explicitly..

Comment: @Jaiwo99 I doubt if you will get such exception because there is no optimistic concurrency checking here

Comment: I think this strongly depends on the database you use and on isolation level, you use for the sql connection

Comment: @AdrianShum you are right, it depends on database locking strategy..

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with thread-safetiness.  The call is supposed to be thread-safe.

DBMS is going to be smart enough to make sure that one update finish before the other update of the same record comes in (unless you have set it with very low isolation level).  Therefore, if two thread (or process etc) invoke that same method twice (using same balance ID), the same record will be deducted twice.

Comment: How can I make sure my isolation level is legitimate for the task?